# MySQL fulltext search - Only results that contain all words

Tags: mysql

With the following query I get results that contain the words "International" AND "Shipping" and I also get results that contain "International" OR "Shipping". What can I do to ensure that the results contain both words and not just one of them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
SELECT client_company,client_description,client_keywords
FROM tb_clients
WHERE
MATCH (client_company,client_description,client_keywords)
AGAINST ('International Shipping') > 0
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add a `+` in front of every required word and use `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.

[**11.8.2. Boolean Full-Text Searches**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to as implied Boolean logic, in which
>
> ```
>  + stands for AND
>  - stands for NOT
>   [no operator] implies OR
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to make the "+" implicit, i.e. by changing some MySQL mode and match all words even without the need to supply the + on each word?