# Full text search returning to many results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I need to search a text column for the occurrence of certain words in the column.

For instance as an example the column contents may look like:

> KIT: TYPE WELD NECK ORIFICE FLANGE, CONSISTING OF TWO FLANGES WITH
>   JACK SCREWS BUT WITHOUT BOLTS AND GASKETS, RATING CLASS 600, RAISED
>   FACE, BORE TO MATCH .312 IN WALL, MATERIAL FORGED 304 STAINLESS STEEL
>   ASTM-A182 GRADE F304, SPECIFICATION: SP-50-13 REV: 1

Now the user needs to enter into a textbox for instance the following:

> ASTM-A182 F304 WELD NECK

Currently I use this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM commtable WHERE MATCH (ldisc) AGAINST ('" . $ldisc . "' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);";
```

But most records returned (it returns hundreds of records) don't contain all the search terms entered in the text field.

How can I fine tune this full text search (or use another method) to give me a better result more closely to what was entered?

EDIT:
Table type:
[image]

EDIT 2:
It is working now, added this code:

```
if ($ldisc != "") {

$parts = explode(" ", $ldisc);

$tempSQL = "SELECT * FROM commtable WHERE MATCH (ldisc) AGAINST (" . "'";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
    $tempSQL = $tempSQL . '+' . $parts[$i] . ' ';
}

$tempSQL = $tempSQL . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE);";

$sql = $tempSQL;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

And changed the minimum word length to 1.

Comment: If the word searched is contained in more than 50% of the rows it is ignored in FULLTEXT searches.What is the table engine myissam or innodb?

Comment: How can one change that? Or is there a better way of doing this search then by not using full text?

Comment: I cant give a better answer if I dont know what the table engine is.`SHOW CREATE TABLE commtable ` run this query in mysql edit your question with the results.

Comment: Can I ask why you chose to use `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`?

Comment: Based on the documentation. But omitting that does not seem to change the amount of records returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question sounds like basically what you're looking for: [MySQL fulltext search - Only results that contain all words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282679/mysql-fulltext-search-only-results-that-contain-all-words)

`NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` by its nature returns approximate matches. To match all words in `BOOLEAN MODE`, you must add a `+` in front of every required word. For example,

```
MATCH (ldisc) AGAINST ('+ASTM-A182 +F304 +WELD +NECK' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You'll have to split the input string and add the `+` signs. How to do that is left as an exercise to the programmer. =)

Answer (score 1):

Change it to boolean mode

```
"SELECT * FROM commtable WHERE MATCH (ldisc) AGAINST ('" . $ldisc . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE);";
```

Another thing is to keep an eye on [ft_min_word_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)