# selecting one row from db by string

Tags: php, laravel

My problem is that i want select from db one row which is the most similar to a searched text.

```
$string = "I want to buy a new notebook";
```

and in DB i have for example:

```
1st row|  keywords: buy notebook | message: okay i will help u |
2nd row|  keywords: sell notebook | message: okay i will help u |
3rd row|  keywords: notebook exchange | message: okay i will help u |
```

And result will be the first row because it contains notebook even buy and no all rows which contains only notebook.

I hope that u understand what i want.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at full-text search for your database. Guess you want something this topic starter doesn't want ;): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282679/mysql-fulltext-search-only-results-that-contain-all-words

Answer (score 0):

You can use Full text search... Probably you can get the solutions.

> Full-Text Search in MySQL server lets users run full-text queries
>   against character-based data in MySQL tables. You must create a
>   full-text index on the table before you run full-text queries on a
>   table.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE MATCH(keywords,message) AGAINST ('I want to buy a new notebook' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Please read this doc - http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Does it possible that i want search a row which is the most similar to a part of word? For example:

```
$string = "Basicly i am playing a game."
```

but in DB i have only

```
1st row|  keywords: basic, play | message: okay i will help u |
2nd row|  keywords: game, t-shirt | message: okay i will help u |
```

Even if I have only in the string "Basicly" and no "basic"?

Thanks.