# sql get all rows where x contains every word in string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a rough example of my current code. For the purpose of simplicity, I have not included the parameterized queries:

```
if(isset($_GET["q"])) {
    $query = "%" . trim($_GET["q"]) . "%";
    $search = $pdo->query("
        SELECT * 
        FROM test 
        WHERE title LIKE {$query} AND keywords LIKE {$query}
    ");
    var_dump($search);
}
```

Table: test:

```
| title             | keywords       |
| this, is a "test" | this is a test |
```

I've been trying to create a simple search system within my website through the use of basic `SQL`. Most of the time I have been getting positive results - however I have come across a problem which I can't seem to fix after days of research.

If I type in something like `"this is a test"` as a query, I get a row returned with the relevant results. But when I query `"test this is a"`, it returns *no results*.

And if the query has _any__ typos, it doesn't work either. (I've been searching the levenshtein, but no answers work within *MySQL*).

All help is appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: Did you check: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552

Comment: _“But when I query "test this is a", it returns no results.”_ - nothing surprising about that - data that doesn’t exist, is hardly ever found … Are you sure you understood how `LIKE` works? It does not perform a search for individual words, it tries to find what you put between the `%` _exactly_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL fulltext search - Only results that contain all words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282679/mysql-fulltext-search-only-results-that-contain-all-words)

Comment: There would be many criteria you need to cover, like , 1. do you need to check all text in any sequence, 2. do you need by each separate text , 3. at what matched text do you consider to add in search result ?

Comment: There's not much you can do with typos unless you implement a `SOUNDEX` condition using an OR with your `FULLTEXT` search. But it looks like you're looking more for a search engine like Sphinx rather than a query criteria.

Comment: use `match ` in query : example: `where MATCH(title,keywords) AGAINST ('test this is a' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);`

Comment: You can start/think [like this demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ce9b83275e2ab83902eea4f63a891167d72244a)

Comment: This is one of those situations where your SQL DDL (schema design) makes it too hard to write simple SQL DML (query). If you consider a word to be an atomic value then storing words in a sentence means you have a bag of multiple values (1NF violation). In other words, you want to query non-relational data using a (somewhat) relational language and it's not a good fit.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to `alter` table for `FULLTEXT`

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD FULLTEXT(title);
ALTER TABLE test ADD FULLTEXT(keywords);
```

then execute this query using `MATCH`

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('test this is a' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
 OR MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('test this is a' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

I have attached the screen-shot of the result

[image]