# How to require all words in a MySQL fulltext search

Tags: mysql

[MySQL fulltext search - Only results that contain all words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282679/mysql-fulltext-search-only-results-that-contain-all-words)

I am aware that I can put a + in front of each word and use IN BOOLEAN MODE, but that is incredibly messy and possibly dangerous. I would have to do something like

1. split the string on white space
2. check the first character of each search term to make sure that it isn't already a control character
3. add "+" in front of every term
4. concatenate the string back together and hope nothing goes wrong.

Selecting based on AND instead of OR seems like it should be the most basic of operations.